# How can I use unix piping across (compute) nodes?

Tags: unix, pipe, cluster-computing, named-pipes, fifo

I'm trying to set up a pipeline of processing commands with unix pipes and FIFO:s (named pipes).

I also wanted to send/stream the output of the process to another compute node, which can start working on the stream of data as soon as it arrives, that is, I want to "pipe the stdout over to a process on another machine". How can I do that?

E.g. is it possible to set up a FIFO that will in the background write it's content over to a FIFO on the other compute node, or similar?

Comment: Why not just use a sockets library?  netcat and ssh use TCP/IP.  You might get better performance out of SCTP or UDP.

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. I saw netcat supports UDP as well (Just add ```-u``` to both sender and receiver), so I guess that will be the easiest option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `netcat`. In this minimal example, you can pipe the output of `cat` to `netcat` using:

```
cat local-filename.txt | netcat remote-hostname 1234
```

Where `1234` represents the TCP port that is going to be used. In the receiving side, you can use:

```
netcat -l 1234 > filename-on-remote-host.txt
```

where `-l` indicates you are setting up a server. This connection will be closed when the originating netcat process finishes. If you need it to keep going and waiting for the next connection, you can use the `-k` option:

```
netcat -kl 1234 | some-receiving-command
```

In any case you can use the abbreviated `nc` instead of the full `netcat`:

```
nc -kl 1234 | some-receiving-command
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, just use `ssh` for this purpose. The `stdin` of `ssh` is sent to the other host. You can use it for example to send data to a different server using `tar`:

```
tar cvzf - data | ssh otherhost 'cd /tmp; tar xvzf -'
```

Comment: The main concern here, I guess, is the performance of SSH, due to the encryption of all traffic ...